# Python Window Shuts down whenever I try to use Messagebox in the following Way

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle

purpose = None


init_window = Tk()
init_window.geometry("400x300")
init_window.config(bg="turquoise")
init_window.title("Password Manager")

init_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
init_canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200, bg="turquoise", highlightthickness=0)
init_canvas.create_image(130, 95, image=init_img)
init_canvas.place(x=70, y=0)

init_label = Label(text="To access the portal enter your password here:")
init_label.place(x=50, y=180)

init_pass = Entry(width=18)
init_pass.insert(0, "Password")
init_pass.focus()
init_pass.place(x=50, y=210)

init_entry = Entry(width=10)
init_entry.insert(0, "Reader/Writer")
init_entry.place(x=237, y=210)


def take_info():
    global purpose
    password = init_pass.get()
    print(password)
    if password == "WELHAM":
        purpose = init_entry.get()
        print(purpose)
        if purpose == "Writer" or purpose == "Reader":
            init_window.destroy()
            print(purpose)
    else:
        pass


init_button = Button(text="Enter", command=take_info, width=28)
init_button.place(x=50, y=250)
mainloop()


def password_adder():
    def save():
        a = website_input.get()
        b = email_input.get()
        c = password_input.get()
        messagebox.askyesno(title="Password Writer", message=f"Do you wish to proceed?")
        # is_ok = messagebox.askokcancel(title="Password Writer",message=f"Website:{a}\nPassword:{c}\nDo you wish to proceed?")
        # if is_ok:
        #     with open("data.dat", "ab") as file:
        #         data_list = [a, b, c]
        #         print(data_list)
        #         pickle.dump(data_list, file)
        #     website_input.delete(0, END)
        #     password_input.delete(0, END)

        # ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

    window = Tk()
    window.config(pady=20, padx=20)
    window.title("Password Writer")

    img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
    print(type(img))
    canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
    canvas.create_image(130, 95, image=img)
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=2)

    # Labels
    website_label = Label(text="Website:")
    website_label.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
    email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
    email_label.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
    password_label = Label(text="Password:")
    password_label.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)

    # Inputs
    password_input = Entry(width=22)
    password_input.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
    website_input = Entry(width=40)
    website_input.focus()
    website_input.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    email_input = Entry(width=40)
    email_input.insert(5, "shivamrastogi605@gmail.com")
    email_input.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    # Buttons
    button1 = Button(text="Generate Password", width=13)
    button1.grid(row=4, column=3)
    button2 = Button(text="Add", width=37, command=save)
    button2.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

    window.mainloop()


if purpose == "Writer":
    password_adder()
```

I would also like to tell that the program runs fine if we run the password_adder function seprately, without having created the init_window.

Python 3.11 | Tkinter | MacOS

I was hoping for the program to run perfectly. Now I am wondering if there is an error in the program or in my Mac. I had high expectations for the program to execute flawlessly. However, I'm now pondering whether the error lies within the program itself or within my Mac.

Comment: You should only use one instance of `Tk` and `Toplevel` for any additional windows.

Comment: @Rory is right! `window = Tk()` should be `window = Toplevel(init_window)`

Comment: Also, in the future, try to pare your question down to a [mre] - it helps us diagnose the issue more easily when there isn't a ton of code to sift through